# Is there a way to limit the number of results for a Python SEaborn bar-plot (or any chart)?

Tags: python, bar-chart, seaborn

I am trying to create a bar-plot that uses a dataset of causes of death per year by rate of occurance.  This is my current code:

```
top_cause_of_death_barplot=sns.catplot(data=death, x='cause_name', y='deaths',kind='bar',ci=None,legend_out=False,height=10, aspect=1.5, )

plt.xlabel('Causes of Death',fontsize=15)

top_cause_of_death_barplot.set_xticklabels(fontsize=10)

plt.ylabel('Number of Observed Deaths',fontsize=15)

plt.title('Top Five Leading Causes of Death in the United States',fontsize=20)
```

Results: 
[SEaborn bar-plot from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGKeG.png)

Is there any way to limit the number of results based on total number of occurrences, rather than the chart showing upwards of 10 or so results.  In this specific example, I've tried to limit it to the top 5 results, but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: This is not a plotting problem. You need to create a dataframe which only contains those entries you want to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59246091/1356000), you can easily restrict the plotting to the top 5 causes of death by only including those in the `order=` parameter:

```
death = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/hewwo/NCHS_-_Leading_Causes_of_Death__United_States.csv', sep=',', header=0)

plot_order = death.groupby('Cause Name')['Deaths'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).index.values

sns.catplot(data=death, x='Cause Name',  y='Deaths',kind='bar',ci=None, legend_out=False, order=plot_order[1:6])
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing.  I knew that the order parameter was required, but the "1:6" is the only way so far it has actually done something.  Thank you.