# Ordering a barplot by ascending or descending

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, bar-chart

This is my current code using a dataset of causes of death within the united states by number of occurrences:

```
`top_cause_of_death_barplot=sns.catplot(data=death, x='cause_name', 
y='deaths',kind='bar',ci=None,legend_out=False,height=10, aspect=1.5)
plt.xlabel('Causes of Death',fontsize=15)
top_cause_of_death_barplot.set_xticklabels(fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('Number of Observed Deaths',fontsize=15)
plt.title('Top Ten Leading Causes of Death in the United States (1999-2017)',fontsize=20)`
```

This results in a chart that looks like this: 
[image: Original Code]

I was attempting to re-order the graph such that the bars were in descending order.  I added a bit to my code and got this:

```
`result = death.groupby(["cause_name"]) 
['deaths'].aggregate(np.median).reset_index().sort_values('cause_name')
top_cause_of_death_barplot=sns.catplot(data=death, x='cause_name', 
y='deaths',kind='bar',ci=None,legend_out=False,height=10, aspect=1.5, order=result['cause_name'] )
plt.xlabel('Causes of Death',fontsize=15)
top_cause_of_death_barplot.set_xticklabels(fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('Number of Observed Deaths',fontsize=15)
plt.title('Top Ten Leading Causes of Death in the United States (1999-2017)',fontsize=20)`
```

While this code did not give me any errors, all it seemed to do was reorder the bars in a different, random order like so:

[image: Code Version 2 Result]

Why does this happen? What am I doing wrong, and is there some way of rearranging the bars into ascending or descending order that I am not aware of?

Comment: The output you get is ordered by the `'cause_name'` column, just as you specify in `order`. If you want to sort by something else, just do so.

Comment: You sorted your bars alphabetically by cause name. Use `order=result['deaths']` instead.

Comment: Changing the order=results to use the y axis removes all bars entirely, like so: https://gyazo.com/43de0615e82c55c367f93f5690e053dc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass values of `x=` to `order=`. In your case, I would do:

```
death = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/hewwo/NCHS_-_Leading_Causes_of_Death__United_States.csv', sep=',', header=0)

plot_order = death.groupby('Cause Name')['Deaths'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).index.values

sns.catplot(data=death, x='Cause Name',  y='Deaths',kind='bar',ci=None, legend_out=False, order=plot_order)
```

[image]

Or, if you want to remove the "All causes" bar:

```
sns.catplot(data=death, x='Cause Name',  y='Deaths',kind='bar',ci=None, legend_out=False, order=plot_order[1:])
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like a lot of work to perform aggregation to provide information about bar ordering, when Seaborn's barplot() is performing the same aggregation.  I prefer Pandas plotting in this situation: `death.groupby('Cause Name')['Deaths'].sum().sort_values().plot.bar()`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `order` argument of `sns.catplot()` to your preferred order. You can use `df['col'].value_counts().index` to get this order. You haven't provided an example of your data, so allow me to provide an easily reproducible example.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.random.choice(['cat', 'dog', 'hamster'], 100)

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['animals'])

sns.catplot(data=df, x='animals',kind='count',ci=None,legend_out=False,
            height=3, aspect=1.5, order=df['animals'].value_counts().index)
```

[image]

Comment: Apologies, forgot to include the dataset I'm using.  If you still wish to view it, it is here: https://storage.googleapis.com/hewwo/NCHS_-_Leading_Causes_of_Death__United_States.csv. Isn't the method you use the same as mine? I use the order statement, and all that does is sort alphabetically rather than numerically.